# Spring-WS JAXB without XML annotations or how to use a class that cannot be modified

Tags: xml, web-services, jaxb, spring-ws

For Spring-WS I need to use classes that I cannot modify, means I cannot add XML annotations. Is there any way to use those classes without XML annotations but using JAXB marshaller/unmarshaller? I can generate new classes using XSD and then do something like, "pass values from request to generated classes, then from generated classes to the classes that I cannot modify (do all logic using this classes) and then pass results to generated classes and to response". But I think it should be some other way to do that. In Castor there is a mapping is there something the same in JAXB?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/moxy/runtime003.htm).

> In addition to standard JAXB annotations, EclipseLink offers another
>   way of expressing your metadata: the EclipseLink XML Bindings
>   document. Not only can XML Bindings separate your mapping information
>   from your actual Java class, it can also be used for more advanced
>   metadata tasks such as:
>
> - Augmenting or overriding existing annotations with additional mapping information
> - Specifying all mappings information externally, with no annotations in Java at all
> - Defining your mappings across multiple Bindings documentsSpecifying "virtual" mappings that do not correspond to concrete Java fieldsand
>     more.

I've once written a similar implementation for JAXB RI in [Annox](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/ANX/Home), take a look [here](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/ANX/JAXB+User+Guide). In both cases the idea is to put mappings in XML files instead of annotations. I don't know how MOXy does this. Annox provides an "annotation reader" which reads XML resources instead of annotations. Below is an example for the canonical [purchase order](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#POSchema) example:

```
final AnnotationReader<Type, Class, Field, Method> annotationReader = new AnnoxAnnotationReader();

final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

properties.put(JAXBRIContext.ANNOTATION_READER, annotationReader);

final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(
    "org.jvnet.annox.samples.po",
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
    properties);

final Object myObject = context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal( ... );
```

`classpath:org/jvnet/annox/samples/po/package-info.ann.xml`.

```
<package xmlns="http://annox.dev.java.net" xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net" xmlns:jaxb="http://annox.dev.java.net/javax.xml.bind.annotation"
    xmlns:adap="http://annox.dev.java.net/javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters">

    <adap:XmlJavaTypeAdapters>
        <adap:XmlJavaTypeAdapter value="org.jvnet.annox.samples.po.BigDecimalAdapter" type="java.math.BigDecimal" />
    </adap:XmlJavaTypeAdapters>

    <class name="ObjectFactory">
        <jaxb:XmlRegistry />
        <method name="createPurchaseOrder">
            <jaxb:XmlElementDecl namespace="" name="purchaseOrder" />
        </method>
        <method name="createComment">
            <jaxb:XmlElementDecl namespace="" name="comment" />
        </method>
    </class>
    <class name="PurchaseOrderType">
        <jaxb:XmlAccessorType value="FIELD" />
        <jaxb:XmlType name="PurchaseOrderType" propOrder="shipTo billTo comment items" />
        <field name="shipTo">
            <jaxb:XmlElement required="true" />
        </field>
        <field name="billTo">
            <jaxb:XmlElement required="true" />
        </field>
        <field name="items">
            <jaxb:XmlElement required="true" />
        </field>
        <field name="orderDate">
            <jaxb:XmlAttribute />
            <jaxb:XmlSchemaType name="date" />
        </field>
    </class>
    <class name="Items">
        <jaxb:XmlAccessorType value="FIELD" />
        <jaxb:XmlType name="Items" propOrder="item" />
    </class>
</package>
```

`classpath:org/jvnet/annox/samples/po/Items$Item.ann.xml`:

```
<class xmlns="http://annox.dev.java.net" xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net" xmlns:jaxb="http://annox.dev.java.net/javax.xml.bind.annotation">

    <jaxb:XmlAccessorType value="FIELD"/>
    <jaxb:XmlType name="" propOrder="productName quantity usPrice comment shipDate"/>
    <field name="productName">
        <jaxb:XmlElement required="true"/>
    </field>
    <field name="usPrice">
        <jaxb:XmlElement name="USPrice" required="true"/>
    </field>
    <field name="shipDate">
        <jaxb:XmlSchemaType name="date"/>
    </field>
    <field name="partNum">
        <jaxb:XmlAttribute required="true"/>
    </field>
</class>
```

If you can use MOXy, I'd recommend to use MOXy as it is definitely much more mainstream.

SO disclaimer: I'm the author of Annox and it happens to be a suitable tool for this case.